# How to customize my Drupal search?

Tags: views, entities, rules, search

I have a Drupal 7.x intranet and I am using the [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module as the backend (basic out of the box setup). My site has content types and custom fields, but it is not using tags/taxonomy, etc.

I was able to do basic customization on my search as to what content type search results come first, weight, etc.

However, I have a business need to be able to control my search results in a way that will allow me to do the following:

1. Search for the word "USA" and the results returned in my search to
   include nodes containing *America*. Is there a way to do this without something like adding a hidden taxonomy/term field to my content type and specifying "USA, America"?
2. Search for the word "Mandarins" and return results that do not have the word "Mandarins" but instead are in a way related (parent/child), so it would return a "QC Procedures" node from our "processes and procedures" content type? A good example of this would be searching for "Son" and the search returns Father, Mother, Brother, Cousin nodes that show up. Somehow establish parent/child/relationships between these nodes/content types that the Drupal search understands and follows.

Comment: How would you manage the links (like USA > America)? Are they something that needs to be administered via a UI or can it be hard coded?

Comment: I think Apache Solr is able to handle synonyms from its setting file.